# Async pipe to unsubscribe from ReplaySubject

Tags: angular, spinner, rxjs

I have the following service to accommodate for a global spinner in my app:

```js
import {
  Injectable
} from '@angular/core';
import {
  Observable
} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {
  ReplaySubject
} from 'rxjs/ReplaySubject';

@Injectable()
export class SpinnerService {
  private visible = new ReplaySubject < boolean > ();

  showSpinner() {
    this.visible.next(true);
  }

  hideSpinner() {
    this.visible.next(false);
  }

  getSpinnerVisibility(): Observable < boolean > {
    return this.visible.asObservable();
  }
}
```

Then the following just above my `router-outlet` in my main app component:

`<app-spinner *ngIf="spinnerService.getSpinnerVisibility() | async "></app-spinner>`

The question is, should the `async` pipe here function as normal to unsubscribe without memory leaks from this `ReplaySubject` or do I have to manually unsubscribe?

Comment: async pipe will automatically unsubscribe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is absolutely no difference between a `ReplaySubject` and an `Observable` from the subscriber's point of view. You don't have to unsubscribe from an observable when you use the `async` pipe, so it's the same for a `ReplaySubject`.

Comment: Thank you. What's strange is that currently when I use my service from another component, the spinner does not show as intended!

Comment: how do you declare your service inside a module or inside a component ?

Comment: Inside my AppModule's `providers` array; but I'm calling the service from a component in another module, which is itself imported in my AppModule's `imports` array.