# When should I use `publishReplay` vs `shareReplay`?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I already know that

- `publish`  shares a single subscription  and also returns a `ConnectableObservable` ( so we have to `Connect()`)
- `Share()` is `publish().refcount()`

The `Replay` postfix is pretty obvious, it returns its last emission/s.

Let's take for example an Angular HTTP request with present AND future subscription :

```html
<p>{{ (person | async)?.id   }}</p> //present markup

<p *ngIf=”show”>{{ (person | async)?.userId }}</p> <!-- future markup -->
```

If I don't want multiple `http` requests I can use :

```js
publishReplay().Connect()
```

But I can also use: `shareReplay()`, but I'm sure that there is one here that is more correct to use than the other.

**Question :**

When should I use  `publishReplay` vs `shareReplay`? What will be the difference in terms of that HTTP present & future request?

<sub>NB
Why there's no documentation about `shareReplay`?</sub>

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`publishReplay` allows you to controls when the subscription starts. `shareReplay` will start automatically upon the first subscription.

Generally, if the observable is to be used in a template (html file) use `shareReplay`. The advantage being you won't have to worry about unsubscribing etc.

Comment: If so then I don't understand how come refcount is `0` , but still it emits a value  for future subscription  ,is it becuase of the replay ? http://jsbin.com/nirisugudi/edit?html,js,console

Comment: Also , regarding your comment and the template in Question , isnt `|async` also automatically unsubscribes ?

Comment: How do you know when refcount is `0`?

Comment: @martin becuase [it has](http://jsbin.com/nirisugudi/2/edit?html,js,console) `take(1)` so after that it completes and there are no more subscribers , but then after 3 seconds another subscriptions arrives and yet it emit value.

Comment: Again as far as I know even if the `refCount` goes to 0 both `shareReplay` and `publishReplay` will replay the last value if one existed. From (hard gained) experience we generally use `shareReplay` in all our templates. `share` only caused us confusion as the observable is completely restarted if the you subscribe after a subscription using this same shared observable finishes.

Comment: @RoyiNamir Yes that's correct. So is this what you want or not? I don't understand how is this related to your question.

Comment: @JoeKing https://stackoverflow.com/a/43997375/859154 - from here it says that `|async` does unsubscribe replay

Comment: @martin It relates becuase I tried to see how it works. With `share` it uses `refcount` , but if it will be zero , then there will be no more subscriptions (which is the exact analogy to future HTML markup) and still - it does emit value. So I didn't understand how this could be. And then he answered that it's the value from the Replay action. So even if refcount is 0 , the replay will still kick in.

Comment: Yes @RoyiNamir that's correct, `| async` will unsubscribe regardless of the observable's type. What I mean is that, if you use publishReplay() (without refCount) than even though `| async` will unsubscribe, the underlying observable will stay "hot" and will not be cleaned up properly. Hope this make sense.

Comment: @RoyiNamir `refCount()` controls when a `ConnectableObservable` connects to its source Observable. It has nothing to do with the buffer inside  `shareReplay`. In other words, even if `publishReplay` unsubscribes from its parent the buffer still exists and it's sent to every new observer regardless of whether `publishReplay` is subscribed to its source or not.

Comment: Take a look at the [spec file for publishReplay](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/test-file/spec-js/operators/publishReplay-spec.js.html). Scroll down to line 126. This will give you a good idea of how `shareReplay` is expected to work and is probably the closest thing you'll get to official documentation at the moment.

Comment: Joe , to tell you the truth I find it hard to understand your last comment. Looking at the http request ( which completes itself after execution  ,by design) - I can't understand how "_The underlying observable will stay "hot" and will not be cleaned up properly._" . Can you please explain / or best https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h4zaij

Comment: @martin Yes. it took me some time to understand that.:)

Comment: Sorry @RoyiNamir I wasn't talking specifically about your particular example where the underlying observable is a Http request. I would expect both `shareReplay` and `publishReplay` to emit the value received from the Http request even though the underlying request is finished. On the other hand if you used the `share` operator the underlying request would in certain cases be repeated. Its all very confusing I know.

Comment: So if http (lets assume) wasnt complete by design, then increased refcount from 0, would've trigger another request?

Comment: Maybe, I'd have to very that on stackblitz or whatever.

Answer (score 77):

> shareReplay() is basically publishReplay().refCount()

***Definitely not.***

Both `shareReplay` and `publishReplay` (+ calling `connect` on it) will make the observable behind it hot.

But the **very important difference between them is**:

- `shareReplay`: **won't stop** emitting until it's **completed**, no matter if there are no subscriptions anymore or not.
- `publishReplay`: **will stop** after the last subscriber unsubscribes if used together with `refCount`

Imho this is a crucial information.

Comment: Yes very crucial! Also note a new feature (config option) is coming to complicate/simplify things further (specifically regarding unsubscription behavior for `shareReplay`) : https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/3336 - fixed in https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/pull/4059

Comment: [The feature](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#features) has been published with 6.4.0 :)

Comment: Article about the new config object in 6.4.0: https://medium.com/@cartant/rxjs-whats-changed-with-sharereplay-65c098843e95

Comment: Having battled with what the exact difference is for a long time, I found the following article the one to clear this up once and for all for me: https://itnext.io/the-magic-of-rxjs-sharing-operators-and-their-differences-3a03d699d255 It starts with `publish` / `share` (here is where it clicked for me) and expands to `publishReplay` + `shareReplay` lateron

Answer (score 5):

`shareReplay()` is basically `publishReplay().refCount()`

Here is a great article explaingin just that in detail: ["Angular Async Pipes  - Beware the share"](https://medium.com/@mikesnare/angular-async-pipes-beware-the-share-bcc9c1cd849d)

**Edit:**

The right thing to say is:

`shareReplay()` **is similar** to `publishReplay().refCount()`

see [@DevRok's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53979783/776546) for more info why they are not exactly the same.

Comment: See Devrok answer