# Why does publishReplay(1), refCount() replay both the last good value AND the last error?

Tags: rxjs

There's a lot written about the difference between `publishReplay(1), refCount()` and how it differs from `shareReplay(1)`.

The error handling is different. `publishReplay(), refCount()` will replay the error whereas `shareReplay(1)` restarts the stream.

There's also [different handling](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53979783/16940) when all subscribers have unsubscribed.

This question isn't about either of these!

---

What I want to know is why does the following occur:

```
// stream that emits 0, 1, 2, ERROR
const timestamp = () => Number(new Date()) % 100000;
const source = timer(1000, 1000).pipe(
                  switchMap((i) => (i==3) ? throwError('Error at ' + timestamp()) : 
                                            of(i + ' - ' + timestamp()) ));

// subscribe to this stream with publishReplay(1), refCount()
const publishReplayObs = source.pipe(publishReplay(1), refCount());
publishReplayObs.subscribe(x => console.log(x), (err) => console.log('Error: ' + err));

// after it has errored, wait a few seconds
setTimeout(() => {

    console.log('--------- resubscribe -----------');
    publishReplayObs.subscribe(x => console.log(x), (err) => console.log('Error: ' + err));
    
}, 10000);
```

Produces:

> 0 - 11490
>
> 1 - 12223
>
> 2 - 13337
>
> Error: Error at 14216
>
> --------- resubscribing -----------
>
> 2 - 13337
>
> Error: Error at 14216

#### Result:

- The last 'good' value has been stored in the ReplaySubject created by `publishReplay`
- The error is also stored ( I'm not sure exactly where )
- Note: The timestamps (13337 and 14216) are the same - so it's the exact same item AND error observables being replayed.

This was very unexpected behavior to me. Having read that `publishReplay` will replay errors I expected to see only the error and not also the last known good value.

Is this really by design - or just some kind of quirky side effect that's just one of those things?

Comment: It's by design and it's in the `ReplaySubject`: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/6.3.3/src/internal/ReplaySubject.ts#L57-L95

Comment: @cartant it was your helpful answers on other questions that led me to post this. I’m still not understanding the exact reason why you don’t just get the latest ‘result’ whether error or data. And if I want just one ‘thing’ I’d need to switchMap to an object like { error: boolean, result: T | any }

Comment: If you want "just one thing", use a `last` operator before the `publishReplay`. Or, better, use `publishLast`. The `ReplaySubject` replays `complete` and `error` notifications by design.